# Launch app when FCM notification received

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `FirebaseMessagingService` for receiving data from Firebase and I need to open an activity to show that data
Just like skype when new call is come.
It's getting the new message and triggers `startActivity` on `Foreground` but not in background.
This is my service:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

override fun onNewToken(p0: String) {
    super.onNewToken(p0)
}

override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)
    val data: Map<String, String> = p0.data
    if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onMessageReceived: $data")

        val dialogIntent = Intent(this, LocationTrackingActivity::class.java)
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK )
        application.startActivity(dialogIntent)
    }
}
```

}

I've granted `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission and checked it from settings to assure it's enabled.